# Imagine I'm on a spacecraft that was accelerated to 1.0$c$ could I only move backwards?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames, faster-than-light, inertial-frames

Imagine I'm in a sapcecraft<sup>1</sup> that is moving with 1.0$c$ or at least is so close to that speed that a few miles per hour would just be left to reach $c$.

So when I'm traveling now in the direction this thing moves, what would hapen? Would I forcefully be unable to move in that direction, so this thing would be like a rattrap while it is moving at that speed?

Or would I be able to catch up with bypassing lightwaves?

---

<sup>1</sup>This could be a planet, a man made thing a star or what ever would be most reasonable here.

Comment: Why downvoting this? I even made the effort to make it link as duplicate myself. The list under the title when asking is diferent from the "Related" list after posting. So is this really to be considered low quality here?